# Exit code not changing based on the button pressed, Dialog for bash

Tags: bash, dialog

I'm working on a bash script, which uses the exit code from Dialog's radiolist, but every button gives the same exit code.

I've tried to use the previous working code I had from another project, and thats not working either. No matter what button I hit, or if I press ESC, it always exits in code 0. The options I get from the array show properly, and it echo's the user's name, so I don't believe it's that.

```sh
Options=()
for file in * ; do
  Data=`cat $file`
  file=$(basename -- "$file")
  if [ "$Data" ] ; then
    Options+=("$file" "$Data" "OFF")
  elif [ ! "$Data" ] ; then
    Options+=("$file" "OFF")
  fi
done

dialog --title "User Menu" --backtitle "Control Panel v2.0" --extra-button --extra-label "EDIT USERS!" --radiolist "Please Select A User (Hit Space Before Enter!):" 10 30 6 "${Options[@]}" 2>./tn
TN=`cat ./tn`

# Get exit status
# 0 means user hit OK button.
# 1 means user hit CANCEL button.
# 3 means user hit EXTRA button.
# 255 means user hit [Esc] key.
response=$?
if [ "$response" == "0" ] ; then
    echo "Chosen User $TN"
    sleep 1
elif [ "$response" == "1" ] ; then
    echo "Canceling..."
    sleep 1
elif [ "$response" == "3" ] ; then
    echo "Launching User Editor..."
    sleep 1
    sudo bash ./Users.sh
elif [ "$response" == "255" ] ; then
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit
fi
```

I expect when the different buttons are pressed, that the different exit codes are actually used, like if I hit the extra button, then the exit code is 3, not 0.

Comment: your script is checking the return code provided by the previous command, in this case `TN=$(cat ./tn)` which will only be true of false, depending if the file `./tn` exists.. (use `$(...cmd sub)` and join the 1990s ;-) . best to use `case dialog .... ; in 0 ) echo "got a zero: ;; 1 ) echo "got a 1" ;; ..... ;; esac`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I'll should of realized that the cat would of thrown it off, I'll try moving to case though, thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there anything I need to surround the dialog with, it's erroring on the options, and I tried putting it into a variable, but it would just return a empty screen.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing. please include a "sketch" (as I have done above). Are you trying to use `case` or ??? I don't have experience with `dialog` so it may not work the way I would expect. Ah maybe you need `case $( dialog .... ) in ... esac` (as before). Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time to reply back, but I figured it out, I did the dialog, then ```case $? in .... esac```, but the previous error was when I tried to do ```case dialog --option1 --option2 in .... esac```, it would error on --option1.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. I don't use `case` that much, so I thought it was possible to embed a command there, the way you can with `if some_cmd | even_with_piped | stuff ; then.... fi`.

Comment: @shellter `case` checks a single (possibly quoted) word against a list of patterns, so it won't run a command the way `if command; ...` does. Either you or OP may want to post an answer here.

Comment: @muru, right. so you ***could*** construct some line like `case $( long_cmd|with_pipes; echo \$?) ; in 0 ) ... ;; 1 ) ...;; * )....;; esac`, but it would require that none of the command(s) (pipe-lined or not) don't emit any text that could be captured by `$(...)`. (well `cmd >/dev/null` could solve that too). In any case a maintenance nightmare, and not recommended.. What OP has done, `rc=$?` ; case $rc ...` is the easiest to understand. Won't be posting an answer, maybe @Waterspark63 will. Good luck to all!